# I want to return True/False on whether a value is in a group of values

Tags: c++, operators, rcpp

In RStudio i can use the following code to see if my value on the left is in the group on the right and return True/False. How would i go about doing this in C++?

```
> 5 %in% c(4,8,10)
[1] FALSE
> 5 %in% c(4,5,10)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: You could use `find`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: @Eljay The question is specific to the `rcpp` tag.  Still a poor question though.

Comment: [`std::any_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Comment: OP is asking about R, even though he only mentions RStudio, which is poor style. In R, logical variables can have _three_ values: true, false, or NA.

Comment: saying c++ in the question seemed like more people would understand... people who know c++ may not know what Rcpp is but Rcpp users will know c++. In hindsight i should have removed the Rcpp tag. I'm not sure what you mean by "In R, logical variables can have three values: true, false, or NA". The above code can only return True or False. Maybe i'm misunderstanding your meaning here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This seems to work: "std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value)  != vec.end()". I don't have a clue what it's doing though. If i remove "!= vec.end()" the other part of the code seems to only return True regardless of what value is and "vec.end()" run on it's own also only returns True, so the whole statement seems to be saying "True not equal to True", but this can't be correct as the code works correctly i.e it returns True if value is in the group and False if it isn't.

Comment: If the value is not found, the `std::find` returns `vec.end()`.  (The `vec.end()` iterator is _past_ the end of the vector.  Iterators are half-open ranges, `[begin, end)`.)

Comment: You might want to take a look at `std:set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in()` function available with Rcpp to recreate `%in%` infix operator.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector match_with_in(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                                  Rcpp::NumericVector y) {

  // Mimic %in% with Rcpp
  Rcpp::LogicalVector matched_values = Rcpp::in(x, y);

  return matched_values;
}
```

Test:

```
x = 5
y = c(4, 8, 10)
match_with_in(x, y)
#> [1] FALSE

z = c(4, 5, 10)
match_with_in(x, z)
#> [1] TRUE
```